# how to display post element in different style in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

currently i am devloping news portal in laravel.  some posts fetching from the database. I want to give different style to posts in above pattern.

I have managed to give a different style to the first post using blade's
how can i do using loop..?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkl6x.png]

Answer (score 0):

Use an `@foreach` to insert your posts in a div. Make sure each post is in it's own div. Then, use a [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) to size your posts appropriately.